# DataFrame of lists to appropriate series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the dataframe `df` defined below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
        [[6], [7, 8, 9, 0]]
    ], list('AB'), list('XY'))
```

How do I get it to

```
A  X  0    1
      1    2
   Y  0    3
      1    4
      2    5
B  X  0    6
   Y  0    7
      1    8
      2    9
      3    0
dtype: int64
```

---

**What I have tried**
I started by admonishing the person who did this.  That did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `stack` a couple times and applying `pd.Series`:

```
df.stack().apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int)
```

The resulting output:

```
A  X  0    1
      1    2
   Y  0    3
      1    4
      2    5
B  X  0    6
   Y  0    7
      1    8
      2    9
      3    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Still waiting on one that preserves int without astype

Comment: The issue with that is that `df.stack().dtype` gets you to dtype = object.  So even `df.stack().apply(pd.Series, convert_dtype=False, dtype=int)` will yield floats, oddly.

Comment: @BradSolomon there is a way!

Comment: Yours is still faster.  `pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in df.stack().iteritems()})`